# Regioselectivity for double elimination of dihalides

Tags: organic-chemistry

I came across a question shown below,

[image]

When predicting the product, I thought the internal alkyne would be preferred over the terminal alkyne as the former would be more substituted. However, the book states that the terminal alkyne should be the answer.

I was thinking that this could be due to the formation of the acetylide ion, which favors the terminal alkyne formation. Would this assumption be correct?

If that is the case, what is a way to form an internal alkyne using elimination?
Also, if the reagents were not excess $NaNH_2$ and just like 2 equivalence, would the internal alkyne be the product as the acetylide ion cannot form without three equivalence of sodium amide?

It would be great if I could receive some clarification over this!
Thank you :)

Comment: 2-Butyne will be isomerized to 1-butyne with $\ce{NaNH2}$ and then deprotonated. The allene, 1,2-propadiene, is the intermediate. Water work up gives 1-butyne itself. It is called a ["zipper reaction"](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/Varrentrapp/varrentrapp.html).